# Nodemailer not sending email on heroku

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, nodemailer

While working on localhost, it sends emails without any problems, but after publishing the project on heroku, it does not send emails online, why?

```js
const transfer = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    port: 587,
    secure: false,
    auth:{ 
        user:"******@gmail.com",
        pass:"******"
    }
});

let mailBilgi = {
    from: "*******@gmail.com",
    to: email,
    subject: "Hesabınız başarıyla oluşturuldu!",
    html: `
        <p>Lütfen hesabınızı aktifleştirmeniz için aşağıdaki linke tıklayınız:</p>
        <a href='http://localhost:3000/verify/${ids}'}'>Aktifleştir</a>
        <p>Garavolli Ekibi</p>
    `
};

transfer.sendMail(mailBilgi, err => {
    if(err){
        next(err);
    }
});
```

Comment: I've checked my version of mailer that works from heroku, some of the differences that I can see is that I have `secure: true` and I don't have port specified, maybe worth a try?

Comment: Try adding console.log/console.error statements so that you can debug and know what going on with code in Heroku

Comment: `secure: true` seems to want port `465`, if the documentation is any indication: https://nodemailer.com/smtp/

Comment: None of what you said worked. :(